# Unjustified downvoting, closing and voting for deletion. What am I supposed to do?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

A question I asked on SO was closed and voted for deletion. I couldn't understand why, and the downvoters / voters for closing told me to take it to Meta, so here I am.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181264/how-can-a-plug-in-enhance-ankis-javascript) is very specific. It asks about solving a specific question in a specific environment (JavaScript provided by PyQt, as used in Anki). I couldn't find an answer on the web. People I asked who are familiar with writing plug-ins for Anki found the question worthy, but unfortunately they didn't know the answer, which is why I took it to SO, with the hope that someone with enough PyQt expertise would see it and tell me either it can't be done or how it can be done.

My guess is the question was not clear enough to some people - who, I presume, have nothing to do with PyQt and/or with writing plug-ins for Anki - who mistook it for being too vast, and so downvoted it, voted it for closure, and then for deletion. I can understand how this may seem the case to someone not dealing with plug-ins for Anki, but it's not the case. And I can't understand their relentless actions, even following my explanations in the comments. If the question is re-upvoted and reopened then someone with the relevant knowledge might just be able to notice it and answer it.

In addition to my hope that my questions will get the justice it deserves, I think there's something wrong in the process if a question that is specifically tagged for a specific environment gets closed because it is not properly understood by users not familiar with that environment. (It's perfectly alright that they don't understand the question, but shouldn't they give others, who are more suitable to answer it, the chance?)

What do you think?

Comment: You are asking SO users to write a book.  You are not going to get one.  Be specific about the problem you need to solve, surely there's some kind of aspect about Anki that you truly struggle with.  Never avoid mentioning what you already understand and what you have a problem with.  Post a snippet that shows what you tried, doesn't matter that it completely doesn't work.  But it shows us what you misunderstand.  If there's evidence that you just didn't make any effort, much like your question reads now, then *do* expect the question to be voted on like this.

Comment: @Hans: I am not asking for a book, I am asking for something very specific, regarding one "aspect about Anki I truly struggle with", and I'm asking very explicitly about this specific thing (adding JavaScript functions my plug-in will implement). The sad thing is the people who think my question is too broad won't be able to help me even if I specify more, so I actually need to put more energy in order to convince some users that my question is worthy, only so that other users - who could have understood my question perfectly the way it was! - would get the chance to answer it :-(

Comment: "I need to write a search engine how do I do it" This is an example of a bad question.  Way too broad, no effort, no real problem other than you need to start researching or prototyping.  "I'm writing a search engine, and I'm using Lucenne, but I don't understand why my stop words aren't being stripped out.  Here's how I'm parsing my inputs..." This is the same person with a good question.  Notice how they are programming, not thinking about programming.  They are facing a concrete development issue and can give us code and details of what has been tried.  See the difference?

Comment: @Will: I do see the difference, I only fail to see the relevance, as my question was much more like the second one than the first one. I guess it wasn't clear enough, that's all. I reposted it with a much longer explanation (but not really with more information) and got upvoted and a link that might lead to an answer :)

Comment: @Tom: Yeah, I read your question.  It was absolutely the first one.  Look at my second example again.  Programming has started, issues have been encountered, and now a question can be answered for that code with that particular framework.  Your question, boiled down, was "Does anyone know if and how this can be done?"  Or, transformed to my first example, "I'm writing a search engine.  Does anyone know if and how this can be done?"

Comment: This question shouldn't have been deleted so quickly, especially not with so much activity from you in the comments trying to figure out what to do about the closure. It should absolutely have been closed as it stands, however. You can still edit it even while it's deleted, though, and raise a flag for undeletion afterwards.

Comment: @Will: The thing is I wasn't asking how to build a search engine, but rather something much more specific: how to add a function to Anki's JavaScript. See the difference?

Comment: @Josh: Thanks for your comment! In the meanwhile I have taken some things into consideration and reposted, and possibly have even gotten an answer :) But I think you're perfectly right, and that the process should involve more of a dialogue (which happened, eventually, but perhaps too many hours, comments and domain-name prefixes too late...).

Comment: @Tom: Bro do you even analogy?

Comment: @Will: I can understand that some people didn't understand my question - at "best" that makes it unclear, but it was very specific with nothing "broad" about it.

Comment: Social exchange, democracy, good opportunity to crap on someone because you're an ironical wisenheimer.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is broad. It asks for advise how to write a plugin.

At Stack Overflow, we like to help, but we need some effort from your side. Show us what you have done. Show us a specific problem (an error or some unexpected behaviour), so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: My question is not how to write a plug-in: it is how to add functions to PyQt's JavaScript, which my plug-in will implement (in Python).

Comment: Ok, then you should reword it. Because the way it is worded, points in this direction. (By the way I added the tag for you).

Comment: And still the advice for specific problems stands.

Comment: @Tom: as a Qt and PyQt user, I do not understand what you mean by PyQt's JavaScript. Do you mean QtScript, QML, some python javascript integration? What adding a function means for you is a another mystery. I do not necessarily need answers, but see how confusing it is to an experienced user without showing some pseudo code, providing more specific description, etc. It could mean so many things to me. If you listen to people and help them to try to help you, it will be reopened and or perhaps even upvoted.

Comment: @Laszlo: I meant specifically the JavaScript capabilities of Anki. If it really isn't clear, I will reword.

Answer (score 6):

> People I asked who are familiar with writing plug-ins for Anki found the question worthy,

Multiple things come to mind here:

1. A lot of questions which are "worthy" in a general sense are not a good fit for Stack Overflow.
2. Did those people specifically state that the question was a good fit *for Stack Overflow*? Or that it was a worthy question, generally speaking?
3. If they *did* state that the question was a good fit for Stack Overflow, then how much experience do they *actually* have with Stack Overflow?

> My guess is the question was not clear enough to some people - who, I presume, have nothing to do with PyQt and/or with writing plug-ins for Anki

I find baseless the suggestion that the problem is that the people who voted to close or downvoted the question do not possess enough knowledge. I've written plugins for Anki. Not once did I have to worry about JavaScript. It is in fact possible to even write an Anki plugin that does not do anything with the UI. Some of my plugins deal with the UI and have to use Qt. One of my plugins does not use the UI at all because it modifies how Anki saves its backups.

So here you have a person that wrote Anki plugins asserting that your question was correctly closed as too broad. It could also have been closed as "unclear". The question should specifically explain what "enhance Anki's JavaScript" means concretely. It should also cover what you've tried. The issue with this is not *primarily* "show me your effort" but that if you've shown what you've tried the answerers have at least an *idea* of what you know and what you don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Louis. My question was worthy in the sense that it asked for a solution for a specific programming problem. Following the debate which evolved I read a few posts about what questions are considered on-topic and what a good question for SO is, and I think my question clearly meets the criteria. My colleagues are not on SO and don't know what a good fit for SO is, but they were very surprised to see what had transpired when I sent them the link to my question.

Comment: If you as a person who's written Anki plug-ins don't understand my question, maybe I have to agree that it was unclear. I think a more constructive way to handle such a situation would be to comment that what I'm trying to do is not clear and have me write in more detail, rather than have the question downvoted and closed within minutes.

Comment: @Tom: you worry too much about downvotes. As for the reason, the closure always has a reason what the OP needs to improve in order to get the question reopened. Your colleagues who are not even aware of SO, and will likely support you accordingly, are not objective measures. Instead of doing this long discussion, you could have updated your question with a couple of sentences to make it clearer. Why argue with everyone here instead of improving your post to give more chance to people to help you out and for the posterity to read something cool?

Comment: @Laszlo and Louis: thanks. I hope to learn with time :) Can one or both of you please see my updated question and let me know if it still needs improvement? (And perhaps answer it? ;-) ) Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23183105/how-can-a-plug-in-enhance-ankis-javascript